# Cumulocity using custom type properties in esper statements

Tags: cumulocity

I have a hard time using the properties of my custom types to write statements like contexts. For exemple, this is working:

```
create context TripContext
  context PartionBySource
    partition by source from EventCreated,

  context ContextBorders
    initiated by EventCreated(
      type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport") as startEvent

    terminated by EventCreated(
      type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport") as endEvent;
```

However it's not enough and I need to check some of my custom properties to better define the context. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
create context TripContext
  context PartionBySource
    partition by
      source,
      getString(????, "customProp1"),
      getNumber(????, "customProp2"),
      ...
    from EventCreated,

  context ContextBorders
    initiated by EventCreated(
      type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport",
      getString(startEvent, "c8y_SwitchPower.newStatus") = "ON") as startEvent

    terminated by EventCreated(
      type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport",
      getString(endEvent, "c8y_SwitchPower.newStatus") = "OFF") as endEvent;
```

I have no idea what to put instead of the ???? to make reference to the event. It's transparent for the "native" properties like source, time, type, etc. but as soon as there is a custom property, I have no idea how to access it.

As for the initiated/terminated syntax, there is something really weird I dont understand, but maybe it's more an Esper than Cumulocity problem. This is working:

```
terminated by EventCreated(
  type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport",
  getString(endEvent, "c8y_SwitchPower.newStatus") = "OFF") as endEvent
```

But this is not:

```
initiated by EventCreated(
  type="c8y_SwitchPowerReport",
  getString(startEvent, "c8y_SwitchPower.newStatus") = "ON") as startEvent
```

I got an error saying:

> Failed to validate single-row function parameter expression 'startEvent': Property named 'startEvent' is not valid in any stream

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also couldn't find a quick way to get it run like you try.
But I would recommend the following approach. If you anyways relating heavily on custom fragments it makes sense to run the event through an additional stream that extracts this values:

```
create schema MyCustomEvent(
  event Event,
  myCustomString String,
  myCustomNumber BigDecimal
);

insert into MyCustomEvent
select
  e.event as Event,
  getString(e, "myCustomString") as myCustomString,
  getNumber(e, "myCustomNumber") as myCustomNumber
from EventCreated e
where getString(e, "myCustomString") is not null
and getNumber(e, "myCustomNumber") is not null;
```

Now you can easily create a context on MyCustomEvent instead on EventCreated.

Comment: Okay but the thing is I have two kind of events: SwitchPower with a prop that says "ON" or "OFF" that I'd use to set the borders of my context (initiated and terminated) and then the multiple events CarDriving in between that have speed and other properties I need to make stats on. So assuming I create my context with SwitchPower events, how will I be able, while referencing this context, to select events from another (probably also custom) table that would still be bordered by event of the context?

Comment: You can spread the context partition over multiple streams. Let's say you created 2 schemas like in my example named SwitchPower and CarDriving. You can create the context partition like this:

`create context MyContext
  partition by 
    event.source.value from SwitchPower,
    event.source.value from CarDriving;`

Comment: Okay but how do I request them in a select after that? Let's say I want to create one measurement containing: the creationTime of the SwitchPower(type = "ON") event as startDate, then the creationTime of the SwitchPower(type = "OFF") event as endDate then counts, avgs, etc. of all the CarDriving events that happened in between. All that in the same Measurement. How should I write that?

Comment: If you check out 4.2.6.2. in the esper docs there are some fixed context properties startTime and endTime that you can get from the context itself. Note that these are the server timestamps of when the event arrives not the timestamp in the event. Not sure if that is close enough for you. Another approach could be to query the 2 events from database again when the context expires. I don't think there is a way to get the events that initiated/terminated the context

Comment: Let's imagine a simpler use case: I have a door sensor sending an event every time the door is opened/closed. What would be the correct way to log the duration the door stayed open for example?

Comment: To calculate it based on the timestamps in the events you can simply use a pattern like this (Imagine we already filtered door open and closed into new streams with the same structure as EventCreated): `pattern[every open=DoorOpen -> close=DoorClose(source.value = open.source.value)]`

Comment: You mean using startTime and endTime but we can't use the timestamps of when the event arrives, because we don't know if the event are gonna arrive straight away or with a delay, we need to use properties that have been set by the device (we're not working with doors but with trackers in cars that may buffer communications in case the network is unavailable at the moment).